# Hive with multiple subqueries

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

I am trying to run multiple sub queries into a where clause, and I get the error below. Does mean that Hive doesn't support it? If not, is there a different way to write the query below?

Error occurred executing hive query: OK FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10249]: Line 14 Unsupported SubQuery Expression 'adh': Only 1 SubQuery expression is supported.

```
select
    first_name, 
    last_name,
    salary,
    title,
    department
from 
    employee_t1 emp
where 
    emp.salary <= 100000
    and (
        (emp.code in (select comp from history_t2 where code_hist <> 10))
        or 
        (emp.adh in (select comp from sector_t3 where code_hist <> 50))
    ) 
    and department = 'Pediatrics';
```

Comment: [Docs say they are supported](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+SubQueries#LanguageManualSubQueries-SubqueriesintheWHEREClause). Not sure about multiple, though.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Gordon. using Joins you can try below query(not tested):

```
 select
    a.first_name, 
    a.last_name,
    a.salary,
    a.title,
    a.department
from 
    (Select * from employee_t1 where 
    emp.salary <= 100000
    and department = 'Pediatrics') a
left outer join (select comp from history_t2 where code_hist <> 10) b
on a.code = b.comp   
left outer join  (select comp from sector_t3 where code_hist <> 50) c
on a.adh = c.comp
where b.comp is not null
or    c.comp is not null
;
```

Comment: In the subqueries it should be `select distinct comp`

Answer (score 0):

Two options.  One is `join`s and the other is `union all`:

```
where emp.salary <= 100000 and
      emp.code in (select comp
                   from history_t2 
                   where code_hist <> 10
                   union all
                   select comp
                   from sector_t3
                   where code_hist <> 50
                  ) and
      emp.department = 'Pediatrics';
```

This isn't normally recommended because there are fewer options for optimization.  But if Hive has this limitation (and I haven't tried this type of query in Hive), then this might be one way around it.

The `join` method would be most appropriate if the `comp` fields were unique in the two tables.  Otherwise, you need to remove the duplicates to avoid duplication in the `join`.

Answer (score 0):

Just adding a little note here. The error message states that hive supports only 1 subquery. That is in fact related to the limitation that hive has: "Only one subquery expression is supported for a single query".

You can refer to the official documentation here. 
https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.6.5/bk_data-access/content/hive-013-feature-subqueries-in-where-clauses.html

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly what `left semi join` is for:

```sql
select
    distinct main.*
from
(
select
    emp.first_name, 
    emp.last_name,
    emp.salary,
    emp.title,
    emp.department
from 
    employee_t1 emp
left semi join 
        (select distinct comp from history_t2 where code_hist <> 10) emp_code on emp_code.comp=emp.code
where 
    emp.salary <= 100000 and emp.department = 'Pediatrics'
union all
select
    emp.first_name, 
    emp.last_name,
    emp.salary,
    emp.title,
    emp.department
from 
    employee_t1 emp
left semi join 
        (select distinct comp from sector_t3 where code_hist <> 50) emp_adh on emp_adh.comp=emp.adh
where 
    emp.salary <= 100000 and emp.department = 'Pediatrics'
) main
```

Ref: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Joins

Comment: Suppose there is a row that satisfies both `code` and `adh` conditions. With `union all` this row will appear twice, but in the original query in the question it will only appear once. Using `union` will help remove the duplicates. If `employee_t1` table has duplicates, both `union` and `union all` will fail, and `distinct main.*` will incorrectly remove such duplicates.